# How do i remove files from my ubuntu one folder

Tags: ubuntu-one

I need some help on removing some files from my ubuntu one account and I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Ubuntu Account is set to be synced with the desktop then navigate to **Home folder -> Ubuntu One** folder. Deleting/adding files there will sync it with the cloud. Else, you could always used the web-interface - [UbuntuOne](https://one.ubuntu.com/), log in with your credentials and modify the required files as you please there.