# How do I remove a folder from the Ubuntu One "Folders" tab

Tags: ubuntu-one

How do I remove a local folder from Ubuntu One operation?  I unchecked the "sync locally?" checkbox, whatever that happens to mean.  I prefer to just get rid of it from the Ubuntu One dashboard.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65918/how-do-i-remove-files-from-my-ubuntu-one-folder?rq=1). Possible duplicate.

Comment: That link goes to a question about files. My question is about the folders in the Folders tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to go to your Ubuntu One account via a browser. Delete the folder as shown in the browser. At some indeterminate time in the future, which may or may not require re-enabling syncing or reloading the desktop Ubuntu One control panel, the folder will disappear from the desktop Ubuntu One control panel, without affecting the file system, so you will still have the actual folder in your Linux file system.

This is incongruous since the addition of the folder happens via the desktop Ubuntu One control panel so it's reasonable to expect there to be a way to do the deletion on the control panel, but I haven't found one.

Answer (score 2):

In nautilus, right click on the folder, enter the Ubuntu One submenu, click on "Stop Synchronizing This Folder". The same menu is also available under "File" when viewing the folder:

[image: Stop Synchronizing This Folder in the Ubuntu One nautilus folder menu]

If the folder contains published files or shared folders you'll be warned,

[image: confirmation dialog if you've made elements of a folder available to others]

And that's it, the folder is no longer extant. You need to refresh the nautilus window for the menu to be updated, however.

Alternatively, `u1sdtool` is a commandline tool with which you can list, create, delete, subscribe and unsubscribe from folders.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-file-sync/)

it works for files and folders. You can browse to your ubuntu one account, click on the 'more' menu for a folder and select delete folder. It will be removed from your ubuntu one account, not your local driver.

[image]

hope that helps

Comment: I have this problem , and non of the suggestions here work. Right-clicking the folder in nautilus doesn't give the option to remove from Ubuntu one and on the Web site in Ubuntu One nothing happens when I click on "more"

Comment: Web interface works for deleting sub-folders of a root shared folder.  Local seems to work best for deleting individual files.